# Rails render forms in same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my scenario 
I have a Stories controller that has a form to create a new Post :

```
stories.show.erb
...
<%=link_to("Create new post",new_story_post_path(@post))%>
```

This new post is generated by Posts controller

```
posts\new.erb
<%= form_for [@story,@post] do |f|%>
```

I want to break away from the traditional behavior - I want the new post form to be displayed inside the same 'story' page and NOT have a full page reload and appearing in a new page .

What's the best way to do this in rails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I think in your case it'll be best if you **add the form in your stories show view and make it as hidden and then when a user clicks on the link to create a new post you can show them your form.***

```
def show
  @story = Story.find(params[:id])
  @post = @story.posts.build # assuming stories have many posts
end

#show.html.erb
...
<%=link_to "Create a new Post", "#", id: "post-link"%>

<%= form_for [@story,@post], html: {id: "new-post"} do |f|%>
  // form fields
<% end %>

#some_file.js
$(document).on("click","#post-link",function(){
  $("#new-post").show();
});

#some.css.scss
#new-post{display:none;}
```

Comment: I think it's a good solution but the javascript should show the hidden form , not the link ...

Comment: @Joel_Blum Can you explain why do you think javascript should show the form?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you , the form is hidden and you set a listener that shows $(this) which is the link to the new form (but the link is already visible and we should show the hidden form) , no?

Comment: @Joel_Blum ahh my bad didn't notice i was using this in jquery. Updated my answer

Comment: also , I had to add  :remote => true to link_to to make this work

Comment: @Joel_Blum remote: true on what? You need it only if you want your form or link to send ajax request which in this case we don't need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60737/discussion-between-joel-blum-and-mandeep).

Answer (score 0):

you could write:

```
<%= form_for [@story,@post], remote: true do |f|%>
```

in create.js.erb you could write

```
$('#post_block').html("<%= render 'your partial with posts' %>")
```

Comment: I don't Ajax is needed here and OP wants to show new post form without reload